# Cannot add object to context.DbSet. SaveChanges not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have this GET method in controller:

```
public ActionResult Reserve(int id)
{
    ViewBag.staffID = new SelectList(context.Staffs, "staffID", "fName");
    ViewBag.roomID = id;
    return View();
}
```

the corresponding view:

```
@model _00002165.Models.Reservation

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Reserve";
}

<h2>Reserve</h2>
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


    <div class="editor-label">
        <label>Room Number</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="text" value="@ViewBag.roomID" readonly name="roomID"/>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fromDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.fromDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fromDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.toDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.toDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.toDate)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <label>Staff:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("staffID", "Select Staff")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.staffID)
    </div>

   <button type="submit">Reserve</button>
}
```

and I want to save the data from these inputs with these POST method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Reserve(Reservation res)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var customer = context.Customers.First(x => x.username == User.Identity.Name);
        res.customerID = customer.customerID;
        context.Reservation.Add(res);
        context.Entry(res).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0).
```

People suggest I add `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.reservationID)` to my view.

But `model.reservationID` is empty.

How can I fix this?
Please help

Comment: You should return a `Reservation` in the get method.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be passing your data transfer objects to/from your views.  Create a view model with a ToModel method that will return the DTO that you want.  Adding to the context, you don't need to change the state.

Use this

```
context.Reservation.Add(res);
context.SaveChanges();
```

removing

```
context.Entry(res).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

If you are trying to update, pull the record from the database, make the changes and call SaveChanges

Answer (score 0):

`context.Entry(res).State = EntityState.Modified;`

This line is not necessary - this would be if you are manually marking something as modified. Since you're adding a brand new entity, the correct value would be `Added`, and that should be there by default.

It seems that is it's trying to do an `update` instead of an `insert`, which results in that error.